Shape-outside CSS property works in Chrome but doesn't work in Safari
Dear Stackoverflow community,
I hope you can help me. My main problem is that the shape-outside CSS property works in Chrome but doesn't work in Safari


.oligosacharid-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.oligos-img {
  min-width: 75%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -43%;
  shape-outside: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0809/8955/2985/files/Anyatej.svg?v=1712226356);
  shape-margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<div class="oligosacharid-container container">
  <h2>Mitol olyan különlegesek az anyatej oligoszacharidok?</h2>

  <img class="oligos-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0809/8955/2985/files/Anyatej.svg?v=1712226356" alt="anyatej oligoszacharidok előnyei" width="auto" height="auto">

  <div class="oligos-text-wrap-1">
    <h3>Ellenállóak</h3>
    <p>Nagyrészben átjutnak az emésztőrendszerünk felső részén, hogy épségben elérjék céljukat, a vastagbelet<sup>4</sup></p>
  </div>
  <div class="oligos-text-wrap-2">
    <h3>Szelektívek</h3>
    <p>Elsősorban a hasznos bélbaktériumokat ( pl.: bifidobaktérium ) táplálják<sup>2,4</sup></p>
  </div>
  <div class="oligos-text-wrap-3">
    <h3>Specifikusak az emberre</h3>
    <p>Ilyen formában a természetben csak az emberi anyatejben találhatóak meg<sup>3</sup></p>
  </div>
  <div class="oligos-text-wrap-4">
      <h3>Egyediek</h3>
      <p>Prebiotikus hatásaikon túl egyedi előnyökkel is rendelkezhetnek<sup>2,5</sup></p>
  </div>
  <div class="oligos-text-wrap-5">
    <h3>Alaposan tanulmányozták őket</h3>
    <p>300+ -nál is több tanulmány íródott róluk<sup>4</sup></p>
  </div>
                 
</div>



The results in Chrome (expecting the same in Safari)
Result in Chrome
The results in Safari
Results in Safari
I figured it out that when I remove the left negative margin it wraps the text, but of course that layout doesn't look good:
without margin left

What device are you running the tests on?

Hi Haworth, I have a 2022 Macbook Pro and the system is 14.4.1 (23E224), and iPhone 12 with iOS

What version of Safari? You can see compatibility for this here and it looks like IE doesn't support it at all so you will probably have issues there also

The problem is the definition of -43% - it is related to the nearest containing block, and that varies depending on width. If you play around with that value you'll see the image and text flowing round it on Safari, and vice versa it'll disappear on Chrome for some values. I suspect you are trying to get rid of approx half the image (widthways)? Is that right?

Yes, I would like to achieve that on mobile it only shows only 1 side of the drop, however (as you can see on the pic) it works on Chrome with the -43% negative margin, because the text on the right hug the image properly - because of the outside shape property. On the other hand in Safari the text remain on the right side.

It doesn't work in Chrome at all sizes of viewport, and it will work on Safari e.g. on my iPad given eg. -20%  margin. That is the problem, the image is not being moved by a % of itself.

Sorry I forgot to mention that the problem is only exist below 1000px. I have a totally different code above 1000px

I use grid system and the full drop image without any shape-outside property

shape-outside works in Safari, but it seems not in conjunction with a negative margin.

@BrettDonald it works for me on Safari iOS as long as the negative margin is not so large that the image is completely off the screen.

With your latest snippet I see the text wrapping round the image on Safari (IOS iPad).
